# Java - Writing method for public int indexOf(T element) in a double linked list

Tags: linked-list, indexof, doubly-linked-list

Below I have the int indexOf(T element) method for a double linked list. I need help with the code to make sure it functions properly. The method should return the first occurence of the element in the list or -1 if element is not in the list. Below is the node class it uses. The IUDoubleLinkedList.java class implements IndexedUnsortedList.java which is where the indexOf method comes from. I tried using my indexOf method from my single linked list class but it's not the same so I hope to understand why it would be different and what code is used that is different between the the single and double linked list.

```
public class IUDoubleLinkedList<T> implements IndexedUnsortedList<T> {
private Node<T> head, tail;
private int size;
private int modCount;

public IUDoubleLinkedList() {
    head = tail = null;
    size = 0;
    modCount = 0;
```

This is the indexOf(T element) method

```
    @Override
public int indexOf(T element) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the Node.java class it uses

```
public class Node<T> {
private Node<T> nextNode;
private T element;
private Node<T> prevNode;

/**
 * Creates an empty node.
 */
public Node() {
    nextNode = null;
    element = null;
}

/**
 * Creates a node storing the specified element.
 *
 * @param elem
 *            the element to be stored within the new node
 */
public Node(T element) {
    nextNode = null;
    this.element = element;
    setPrevNode(null);
}

/**
 * Returns the node that follows this one.
 *
 * @return the node that follows the current one
 */
public Node<T> getNextNode() {
    return nextNode;
}

/**
 * Sets the node that follows this one.
 *
 * @param node
 *            the node to be set to follow the current one
 */
public void setNextNode(Node<T> nextNode) {
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
}

/**
 * Returns the element stored in this node.
 *
 * @return the element stored in this node
 */
public T getElement() {
    return element;
}

/**
 * Sets the element stored in this node.
 *
 * @param elem
 *            the element to be stored in this node
 */
public void setElement(T element) {
    this.element = element;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Element: " + element.toString() + " Has next: " + (nextNode != null);
}

public Node<T> getPrevNode() {
    return prevNode;
}

public void setPrevNode(Node<T> prevNode) {
    this.prevNode = prevNode;
}
```

}

Comment: *"I tried using my indexOf method"*: I cannot find your implementation in your code. *"...from my single linked list class but it's not the same"*: there is no reason why it should be different, but you didn't provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code, hope I helped you!

### Insert item at head as well as tail end

```
public void insertItem(T elem) {
    /* if head and tail both are null*/
    if(head == null || tail == null) {
        head = new Node<T>(elem);   
        tail = new Node<T>(elem);
    }else {         
        Node<T> tempItem = new Node<T>();
        tempItem.setElement(elem);  
        /* insert at head end /*                    
        tempItem.setNextNode(head);
        head.setPrevNode(tempItem);
        head = tempItem;
        
        Node<T> tempItem1 = new Node<T>();
        tempItem1.setElement(elem);         
        /* append at tail end */
        tail.setNextNode(tempItem1);
        tempItem1.setPrevNode(tail);
        tail = tempItem1;
                
    }       
    
    size += 1;
}
```

### Print item from head end

```
    public void printItemsFromHead() {
    while(head != null) {
        System.out.print(head.getElement()+" --> ");
        head = head.getNextNode();
    }
   }
```

### Print item from tail end

```
public void printItemsFromTail() {
    Node<T> temp = null;
    while(tail != null) {
        temp = tail;
        System.out.print(tail.getElement()+" --> ");
        tail = tail.getPrevNode();
    }
    /*System.out.println();
    while(temp != null) {
        System.out.print(temp.getElement()+" --> ");
        temp = temp.getNextNode();
    }*/
  }
```

### Implemention of indexOf function

```
  @Override
   public int indexOf(T element) {
    int result = -1;
    int headIndex = 0;
    int tailIndex = size;
    while(head != null && tail != null) {
        if(head.getElement().equals(element)) {
            result = headIndex;
            break;
        }
        /*
        if(tail.getElement().equals(element)) {
            result = tailIndex;
            break;
        } */
        head = head.getNextNode();
        tail = tail.getPrevNode();
        
        headIndex += 1;
        tailIndex -= 1;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

### Driver class

```
public class Driver {
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static <T> void main(String[] args) {
    UDoubleLinkedList uDoubleLinkedList = new UDoubleLinkedList();
    
    
    uDoubleLinkedList.insertItem(1);
    
    uDoubleLinkedList.insertItem(2);
    
    uDoubleLinkedList.insertItem(3);
    uDoubleLinkedList.insertItem(4);
    
    uDoubleLinkedList.insertItem(5);        
    
    System.out.println(uDoubleLinkedList.indexOf(1));
    
  }
 }
```